# Prove that $\|Ax-b\|^2/(1-x^Tx)$ is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

How to prove that the following function:

> Is
> $$f: \mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R,\qquad f(x) = \frac{||Ax-b||_2^2}{1-x^Tx}, \qquad \text{ dom }f=\{x|||x||_2<1\}$$
> convex? Here $\|x\|_2$ is the $2$-norm.

I tried to use the Jensen inequality or the second-order condition, but I can't figure them out. I think that's the wrong direction.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Answer (score 1):

A convex model of the epigraph
$$\left\{(t,x)\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}~:~t\geq \frac{\|Ax-b\|_2^2}{1-\|x\|_2^2}, \ \|x\|_2\leq 1\right\}$$
is given by
$$t(1-s)\geq \|Ax-b\|_2^2,$$
$$s\geq \|x\|_2^2,$$
$$t\geq 0,\  s\leq 1$$
and these constraints are convex because they describe two *rotated quadratic cones* in the sense of second-order conic optimization, see for instance https://docs.mosek.com/modeling-cookbook/cqo.html#rotated-quadratic-cones.