# Prove, that function is convex

Tags: convex-analysis

How to prove, that
$$f(x)=\frac{||Ax-b||^2}{1-||x||^2}, ||x||^2<1, x \in \mathbb{R}^n$$ is convex?

UPDATE:
I've tried the following approach. The function $$g(x) = log(||Ax-b||^2)$$ is convex (proof is straightforward), the same with function $$h(x) = log(\frac{1}{1-||x||^2}), ||x||^2<1$$
The affine combination of $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ is convex too.
$$f'(x)=log(\frac{||Ax-b||^2}{1-||x||^2})$$ And applying increasing function $e^x$ preserves the convexity.

Comment: What's the domain and codomain of $f$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3834326/prove-that-ax-b-2-1-xtx-is-convex/3834352#3834352

Comment: I found an explanation with cones very obscure. I really spend a lot of time, trying to prove, that epigraph of $f$ is a cone, but i failed

Comment: The idea is to describe the set you want as intersections and linear projections of sets you already know are convex, in this case quadratic cones (and hyperplanes, halfspaces etc.). That is often a very natural strategy, and the presence of 2-norms in $f$ is just asking for it. I am pretty sure that any direct proof of convexity of $f$ will at some point be reproving the convexity of those basic building blocks.

Comment: I agree that separating the whole problem on blocks looks very natural here. But still, I feel very uncomfortable with cones :( @MichalAdamaszek can I ask you to criticize my approach to the proof (I've added the update)

Comment: g is not convex.

Comment: Yep, I missed it. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please explain $s > ||x||^2$. How it appeared?